# Saving a value to a database then appending a value to it

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, web, append

So im doing a project and i have made a webpage, on this page i have a total value which is a float inside of a div called total. What i want to do is save this value to a database on my webspace (im hosted by 123 reg) so each user saves the total that they get and then the total in the database in the website is constantly updated and displayed again on the website as a "Global total".

I have no idea about how i would go about doing this any takers?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your problems? Are you using PHP or something similar on the server? What type of Database? MySQL?

Comment: Just been trying to research ways of doing it because i am not at all familiar with it, my problem is the whole concept haha. I can use PHP on it, and its a MySQL database yeh.

Comment: Ok i'll posted you an answer with some starting points. You should try to code something up for yourself and ask questions along that way when you encounter issues. That's the best way to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically you might want to take a look at Javascript, especially how to submit a form using javascript:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Then you want to take a look on how to process this data in PHP.
The data should come in within the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables.

And you might want to learn about SQL `INSERT` statements.
http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-data-into-table.html (somewhere around the bottom)

And then you might want to learn about using the MySQL `SELECT`-Statement. With that you can use a summation operation to get the sum of all totals and then using PHP echo that into the page again.

Or using AJAX you could load it into the page in a somewhat "live" action.